# Sending custom Content-Type with ResponseEntity<Resource>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mime-types, content-type

I am trying to use the ResponseEntity return type in my Spring WebMVC 3.0.5 controller. I am returning an image, so I want to set the Content Type to image/gif with the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/*.gif")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> sendGif() throws FileNotFoundException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
    return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(ctx.getResource("/images/space.gif"), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However, the return type is being overridden to text/html in ResourceHttpMessageConverter.

Other than implementing my own HttpMessageConverter and injecting this into the AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter, is there any way for me to force the Content-Type?

Answer (score 39):

Another proposition :

```java
return ResponseEntity
               .ok()
               .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_GIF)
               .body(resource);
```

Comment: This is much cleaner then setting it in the HttpServletResponse directly.

Comment: Shame this cant be done on a `ResponseEntity.notFound()`...

Answer (score 15):

try injecting the  HttpServletResponse object and force the content type from there.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/*.gif") 
 public ResponseEntity<Resource> sendGif(final HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
            response.setContentType("image/gif"); // set the content type
            return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(ctx.getResource("/images/space.gif"), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks gouki, I'm pretty sure that would work. But, and I should have added upfront, this was an exercise in living the spring dream of decoupling from the servlet API. Normally in this situation I get spring to pass in the HttpServletResponse and write directly to the response output stream. Thanks all the same.

Comment: That was totally awesome. It worked for me 100%. Please note that the   response.setContentType("image/gif"); line does nothing. The key is in  the rest.

Comment: It seems like when you use this technique you might get an 406 error, what solved in my case was returning a ResponseEntity<byte[]> as the SO answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049153/doesnt-accept-spring-mvc-responseentityresource-an-imputstreamresource

Comment: @gouki Is setting headers also necessary or just setting response.setContentType("image/gif"); good enough? what is the difference or need of them?

Comment: What is `Resource` package?

Answer (score 2):

This should be the approach to set all the parameters like httpStatus , contentType and body

> ResponseEntity.status(status).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(response);

This sample is using the ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder interface.

Answer (score 1):

Those two approaches are correct. You can also use 
`ResponseEntity<?>` 
at top so you can send multiple types of data.