# Doesn't accept Spring MVC ResponseEntity<Resource> an InputStreamResource?

Tags: image, spring, spring-mvc, response, inputstream

I'm trying to send a jpg image with Spring MVC using `ResponseEntity<Resource>` as the controller method response type.

If the resource is a `FileSystemResource` it works fine but when I try to use an `InputStreamResource` the `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` ask for the content lenght and `InputStreamResource` throws an exception (from `AbstractResource` method because there is not any file to read lenght from). `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` would continue if the method returned `null` instead.

Is there any other way to manage to use an `InputStream` as `Resource` for the `ResponseEntity`?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy it to an byte array for example (or use the Input stream directly -- I have not tested it with an input stream).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{bid}/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<byte[]> content(@PathVariable("bid") final MyImage image) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(...);
    headers.setContentLength(image.getSize());

    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(this.image.getContentAsByteArray(), headers);
}
```

*Hint: for big content 10MB+ it is important to set the ContentLength. If you miss that some Browsers will not download it correctly. (The exact file size up to which it works without ContentLength is browser dependend)*

Comment: Thank you, InputStream can't be used directly. There is not a `HttpMessageConverter` for that. And doesn't the use of byte array increase the memory usage?

Comment: 1) So you can add your own HttpMessageConterter. - 2) because the file content has to be loaded anyway (And I do not expect that it is implemented in a streaming way) it should be no relevant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=filename.jpg")
            .contentLength(length)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
```